# Displays the title of the selected laravel category

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Gives an error when switching to the `router / catalog / {id}`. Tried to conclude a title of the corresponding category, but apparently did something wrong, please tell me where is the error.

```
             // Routers
             Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');
             Route::get('/catalog', 'SiteController@catalog');
             Route::get('/catalog/{id}', 'SiteController@catalog_page');
             Route::get('/contacts', 'SiteController@contacts');

             //Controllers
             class SiteController extends Controller
             {

               public function catalog()
            {
              return view('catalog', ['menus' => Menu::all(),'products' => Tovar::all()]);
             }
             public function catalog_page($id)
{
             $category = new Menu();
             $category = $category->with('children')->where('id', $id)->get()->toArray();

    return view('catalog_page', ['menus' => Menu::all(),'products' => Tovar::all(),'result' => $category]);
}

         public function contacts()
          {
          return view('contacts', ['menus' => Menu::all(),'products' =>              Tovar::all(),]);
          }
           public function index()
           {
            return view('index',['menus' => Menu::all(),'products' => Tovar::all(),]);
      }
      }

       // Model Menu
     <?php

     namespace App;

     use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

     class Menu extends Model
    {
     protected $table = 'menus';
    }

    // views
    @extends('template')

    @section('content')

    <div class="content__right">

    <h1>{{$result['title']}}</h1>
    </div>

    @endsection
```

```
Undefined index: title (View: D:\OSPanel\domains\blog\resources\views\catalog_page.blade.php) - error
```

Comment: What do you have in `$category`? print the data. check if it is empty.

Comment: If you use ```$category = new Menu();``` of course there will be no title or whatsoever..

Answer (score 0):

check if category is string or array . if it is string you can just

```
// views
    @extends('template')

    @section('content')

    <div class="content__right">

    <h1>{{$result}}</h1>
    </div>

    @endsection
```

if its array than

check if `$category` has **title** key or not. Just print it and verify it.

Can you dump `$category` data and show it.

Comment: <h1><?php print_r ($result) ?></h1> returns an empty array

Comment: if it return empty than how it will print  `<h1>{{$result['title']}}</h1>`. so it gives error.

Comment: what is the solution then in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `$category` doesn't have index `title`.

You can use `dd()` to check the variable `$category` just like this.

```
$category = $category->with('children')->where('id', $id)->get()->toArray();
dd($category);
```

You could do like this:

```
// views
    @extends('template')

    @section('content')

    <div class="content__right">
    @if($result)
    <h1>{{$result['title']}}</h1>
    @else
    <h1>no title</h1>
    </div>
    @endif
    @endsection
```

Comment: returns an empty array

Comment: That's the problem. Empty array doesn't have index: title.